# Why does it say undefined when I log the value [ts][ionic2]?

Tags: typescript, ionic2

```
public lvl:number = 6;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {   
  console.log('Start Page Constructor');
  setTimeout(function(){
        for(var i=0;i<4;i++){
            console.log(this.lvl);
        }
   }, 5000);
}
```

I expected the log to be:

```
6
6
6
6
6
```

But I'm getting:

```
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
```

I do not understand what i'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your `this` changes when you use `function () {}` syntax for callbacks. Use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to get the correct `this`:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    for(var i=0;i<4;i++){
        console.log(this.lvl);
    }
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your `this` is binded to function inside the setTimeout. Have you tried bind the function like this?
`setTimeout(function () { ... }.bind(this), 5000)`